# Python tokenizing words

Tags: python, list, csv, nltk, tokenize

```
summaries = []
texts = []
with open("C:\\Users\\apandey\\Documents\\Reviews.csv","r",encoding="utf8") as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        clean_text = clean(row['Text'])
        clean_summary = clean(row['Summary'])
        summaries.append(word_tokenize(clean_summary))
        texts.append(word_tokenize(clean_text))
```

I just want to tokenize row from csv file and I am getting this error:
 "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: I think row is a list. You can't access elements from a list using string index.

Comment: You probably need [**`DictReader`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Comment: hey thank you.. but when i am using dictreader it is giving me this error:" expected string or bytes-like object" @peter Wood

Comment: Please paste a sample of reviews.csv

Comment: ['Id', 'ProductId', 'UserId', 'ProfileName', 'HelpfulnessNumerator', 'HelpfulnessDenominator', 'Score', 'Time', 'Summary', 'Text']
['1', 'B001E4KFG0', 'A3SGXH7AUHU8GW', 'delmartian', '1', '1', '5', '1303862400', 'Good Quality Dog Food', 'I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have found them all to be of good quality. The product looks more like a stew than a processed meat and it smells better. My Labrador is finicky and she appreciates this product better than  most.']     this is sample csv just one row

Comment: It would be better to access your sumamry and text with integers. like clean_text= clean(row[8]) clean_summary = clean(row[9])

Comment: Edit the question, this isn't a chat forum. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: thanks mufeed.... i tried using that and its still giving me keyerror:8...will be great if u can help me bit here

Comment: Please edit the question with proper input and expected output.

Comment: Also you pasted the input in the form of a list here. I don't think it is in the form of a list in csv file. Please edit the question showing how exactly your csv file look like(first few rows are enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your csv file looks something like this:

```
Id,ProductId,UserId,ProfileName,HelpfulnessNumerator,HelpfulnessDenominator,Score,Time,Summary,Text
1,'B001E4KFG0','A3SGXH7AUHU8GW','delmartian',1,1,5,1303862400,'Good Quality Dog 
Food','I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have 
found them all to be of good quality...'
```

Then you should use DictReader as suggested by Peter Wood in comment section.

```
summaries = []
texts = []
with open("foo.csv",encoding="utf8", newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        clean_text = row["Text"]
        clean_summary = row["Summary"]
        summaries.append(word_tokenize(clean_summary))
        texts.append(word_tokenize(clean_text))
```

**Output:**

```
# texts
[["'I", 'have', 'bought', 'several', 'of', 'the', 'Vitality', 'canned', 'dog', 'food', 'products', 'and', 'have', 'found', 'them', 'all', 'to', 'be', 'of', 'good', 'quality', '.', 'The', 'product', 'looks', 'more', 'like', 'a', 'stew', 'than', 'a', 'processed', 'meat', 'and', 'it', 'smells', 'better', '.', 'My', 'Labrador', 'is', 'finicky', 'and', 'she', 'appreciates', 'this', 'product', 'better', 'than', 'most', '.', "'"]]

# summaries
[["'Good", 'Quality', 'Dog', 'Food', "'"]]
```